# Error occurred on PowerShell that downloads and installs Google Chrome on Windows Server 2016

Tags: powershell, batch-file

This is actual code I tried. Please find the screenshot of the error here https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMWeQ.png

```
@echo off

powershell.exe -Command $Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = "chrome_installer.exe"; Invoke-WebRequest "https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/chrome_installer.exe" -OutFile $Path$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args "/silent /install" -Verb RunAs -Wait; Remove-Item $Path$Installer
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMWeQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer because the code looks horrible in a comment:
Double quote the entire string after `-Command`, this is the entire command sent to `powershell` then single quote the internals (which in the original had double quotes).

```
powershell.exe -Command "$Path = $env:TEMP; $Installer = 'chrome_installer.exe'; Invoke-WebRequest 'https://dl.google.com/chrome/install/latest/chrome_installer.exe' -OutFile $Path$Installer; Start-Process -FilePath $Path$Installer -Args '/silent /install' -Verb RunAs -Wait; Remove-Item $Path$Installer"
```

Comment: May I know why and where this "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" are used?

Comment: `Get-ExecutionPolicy` is exactly that, a policy that allows/restricts execution. you can see what you current execution policy is by running, from `powershell` the command `Get-ExecutionPolicy` which will most probably return `Restricted`. That being said, I am not really understanding your question to why or where it is used?